# How to modify the edit widget in ESRI flex viewer 3.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am running ArcGIS Server 10.0 (sp2) on Windows server 2008 64-bit with IIS 7.  I am using the ESRI flex viewer version 3.0.

I have created a feature layer and published it as a rest service and included a template and use the edit widget with this feature service to allow specific users to modify a single attribute on road features on the feature layer.  The Edit widget, as is, will allow you to select multiple features (in this case, roads), but you cannot update all selected features at once, you have to do it one at
a time.  I want to add a button to the window that appears (the attributes window) that will allow you to apply the change to all selected features.

I have flex builder 4.6 and have created some custom widgets, but this change is a little beyond my skillset currently.  I've looked in the editwidget.mxml and editwidgetattributeinspectorskin.mxml, but don't see where actual edits are made in either of these files.  I'm thinking the actual codeing for applying edits to the selected features is in a different section of the source, but don't know where to look.

Any help is greatly appreciated.